# laravel auth logout how to return new csrf token

Tags: php, laravel, csrf

In my project, i want to login and logout the users without page refresh. To do that, i override the methods sendLoginResponse and logout of the trait AuthenticatesUsers in the LoginController to return not redirects but updated data. I call these methods via ajax.

The problem is when i logout, I need to return to the client a new csrf token to be able to login again without page refresh. When I return a new csrf token like this at logout :

```
public function logout(Request $request)
{
    $this->guard()->logout();

    $request->session()->invalidate();

    return csrf_token();
}
```

the csrf token is null. How can I solve this?

Comment: try `$request->session()->regenerateToken()` before creating `csrf_token()`.

Comment: `$request->session()->invalidate();` causes the problem As. @Wreigh pointed `$request->session()->regenerateToken();` would solve the problem

Comment: thanks guys, this worked.